# Bandwidth and wire parameters

Tags: communication, digital-communications, network

Does the physical features of a wire like surface area, length or specific resistance form any sort of limit to the bandwidth of signals that can be passed through that wire?

Answer (score 2):

Skin effect - a wire will pass current at dc evenly across its entire cross sectional area - this means maximum use is made of the conductor and this leads to lowest resistance against current. As frequency rises however, alternating magnetic fields inside the conductor progressively force the conducted current towards the "skin" or surface of the conductor and very little current flows along the centre of the wire. This can lead to frequency dependent losses. Different materials are worse - iron (because of its high permeability) is pretty useless at frequencies beyond several MHz - its high magnetic permeability forces the "skin" to be very thin and therefore conductivity is very low.

At higher frequencies, having a larger surface area helps with conductivity problems due to skin-effect and I've seen powerful antenna feeds using what might be described as copper pipes - the middle of the pipe is not needed because all the current is conducted in a very thin skin. Why waste the copper and make it heavier?

The end-to-end resistance of a wire is proportional to length. Given that any "series" wire resistance causes a signal loss when there is distributed capacitance to ground (or signal return) the higher the frequency rises the bigger the loss.

Answer (score 0):

*Impedence* is the quantity that matters. This gradually increases at higher frequencies, and attenuates the signal along its length: http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedia/Coaxloss.cfm . It's computed from the physical properties of the wire and its corresponding shield or ground.

The effective data rate over a particular cable using a particular modulation scheme is a function of the *signal-to-noise ratio*, which is affected by induced noise from nearby noise sources as well as the intrinsic thermal noise of the cable.

Comment: Normally when we talk about a cable impedance, we're talking about *characteristic impedance*, not loss terms (though loss terms can be rolled in to the imaginary part of characteristic impedance). Also, noise component of SNR typically depends at least as strongly on the receiver characteristics as on the cable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the physical features do affect the bandwidth ,Because as the frequencies increase the lumped parameter approach of describing a wire fails and distributed inductance and parasitic capacitances comes in to picture.These capacitances and inductances act together to form LC,RL and RC filters either both in series and parallel forms .Depending upon these filter passband,stop band combination the whole wire will attenuate certain frequencies and allows some other frequencies.In microwave engineering book by pozar these kind of filter designing is also mentioned clearly.

Answer (score -1):

In practice, yes. With a simple model of the wire, unlimited power available, and no noise considerations, perhaps not.

[Here](http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/bstj/vol04-1925/articles/bstj4-1-15.pdf) is a paper devoted to telephony. The limit is often called the "[Shannon Limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem)" after Claude Shannon.

Aside from simple attenuation of the signal, dispersion (different delays for different frequencies) will be a practical limitation.

Comment: Shannon's theorem doesn't say anything about how the geometry of a wire relates to its bandwidth. What it tells you is if you have a wire with a given bandwdith (and know the noise contributions in your system), how much information you can pass along the wire.

Comment: Two plain parallel copper wires prone to "receive" noise as the distance increase. This is the relation with S/N and Shannon. So mechanical technics used to keep noise out and not the use of exotic metals. This technics includes coax, twisted pair, houl cables, as well as modulation, inverse multiplexing etc. Fibers have better SNR, but look the entire system, not just the fiber. You can get good quality data rates in Gbit ethernet using copper.
If you want to relate distance and wire cross section area (for skin effect) in wire line, a good formula is B^15*(A/l^2) bits/sec